# Remove /YEAR/MONTH/ From Permalinks Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirectmode

I have a blog on WordPress that was migrated from Blogger so have permalink structure like **`http://www.exeideas.com/2014/10/blogger-to-wordpress-best-htaccess-file.html`** but now I want to rewrite it as **`http://www.exeideas.com/blogger-to-wordpress-best-htaccess-file`** only.

I tried the following codes in my `.htaccess` file but nothing is happening.

```
## Remove /YEAR/MONTH/ From URLs ##
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([^/.]+)\.html$ http://www.exeideas.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
## Remove /YEAR/MONTH/  From URLs ##
```

***AND***

```
## Remove /YEAR/MONTH/ From URLs ##
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([^/.]+)\.html$ http://www.exeideas.com/$1/
## Remove /YEAR/MONTH/  From URLs ##
```

So can you explain the error behind my codes or anything else is happening...???

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the leading slash from your RewriteRule's pattern

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.exeideas.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```